# Django Pyodbc Stored procedure not all arguments converted during string formatting 1- Sql server

Tags: python, django

I am unable to call `STORED Procedure` from `Django`. I am able to call use the `STORED Procedure` from normal `python` program.
Sample working `python`code

```
cursor = connect.cursor()
params=('IBM','2016')
cursor.execute("EXEC SP_Competitor_Extract ?, ? ",params)
```

This piece of code is working fine . But when i am trying to execute from `Django` it does not working .

```
def index(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        params=["IBM", "2015"]
        cursor.execute("{call SP_Competitor_Extract (?,?)}",params)
        while cursor.nextset():
            try:
                results={'results':cursor.fetchall()}
                break
            except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
                continue
```

This is giving me the error message `not all arguments converted during string formatting`

[image]

Comment: include the full traceback of the error

Comment: File "C:\Users\eindswa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py" in format_sql
  509.             sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params))
Exception Type: TypeError at /DS_LAB_4/
Exception Value: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now in `PYodbc` there is no `callproc` . you can pass the argument directly . you dont need the place holder . In my case `cursor.execute("{call SP_Competitor_Extract IBM,2016}")` worked . i am getting all the values as `variable`and creating the `SQL` .`cursor.execute(SQL)`

Answer (score 2):

Django's internal `.cursor()` method differs from pyodbc's method. Try this:

```
cursor.execute(
    "EXEC SP_Competitor_Extract %s, %s",
    [params]
)
```

For more information, the documentation covers it well here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

The other option is to import `connection` from `pyodbc` and create a connection manually like you do in Python, with your Django `DATABASES` settings variables. Good luck!